# Firefox inspector for :before :after

Tags: css, firefox

Can you inspect `:before` and `:after` pseudo attributes in Firefox?
Currently there is only basic support for link pseudos from what I can tell.

Comment: scroll down the inspector and you'll see them

Comment: nope, its nowhere (bad directions) http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/Qpxr

Comment: Could you show your css code?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. For example, every icon on http://glyphicons.getbootstrap.com/ uses `:before`

Comment: @Danield: He's talking about the [inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) not firebug.

Comment: See the chrome inspector http://see.kirkstrobeck.com/Qpp0

Comment: @Kirk Strobeck: It's still a pending issue on bugzilla unfortunately: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694019

Comment: Why did you remove that as an answer?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck: Undeleted :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Unfortunately not as of yet. This is still a pending issue on [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)</strike> - [resolved](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694019)

This is now [supported](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/09/new-features-in-the-firefox-developer-tools-episode-26/) as of Firefox 26.

Comment: Is bugzilla a home for bugs or is it meant to be a place where they resolve them? because it sure seems that bugs have a long lifespan in there .. Reported October of 2011, geesh !

Comment: It's *supposed* to be both :p - I've seen bugs resolved before, though I'm not sure why they haven't included this functionality to begin with, let alone resolve it after all this time.

Comment: Looks like there's a patch waiting as of today, so it might go in somewhat soon if we're lucky...